# Strtotime function return different values on different server

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm making a calendar and it works perfectly on localhost but not in my server site.
I think my problem occurs because of strtotime.

```
while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
        { 
    $start = strtotime($rows['DATEFROM']) * 1000;
    $end = strtotime($rows['DATETO']) * 1000;
    $calendar[] = array('ID' =>$rows['ID'],
    'start' => "$start",
    'end' => "$end"
        );
```

this part of code gives;

```
"start":"1528588800000","end":"1528675200000"
```

so events seems in calendar but in my server site I use IIS server and it gives;

```
 "start":"1528578000000","end":"1528664400000"
```

so events not seems perfectly.

I searched and most of you said that it occurs of timezone but my localhost timezone and server site timezone is same.It's America/Virginia

I know that php.ini file in localhost says that timezone = UTC but I don't know my IIS Server timezone(when I searched the ISS server use server site time)

localost image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwMgV.jpg

serversite image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSNdQ.jpg

database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEs5m.jpg

Comment: I suspect that one is `UTC` as you mentioned and the other `Eastern time` (Virginia). They are different by 4 hours, which is exactly what you would expect here as UTC is 4 hours ahead of Eastern. Perhaps change the timeszone in `php.ini` for `localhost` to `America/New_York` so they match.

Comment: So how can I change the ISS server site "America" to "UTC" because UTC timezone gives the correct  answer

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Set `date.timezone` in `php.ini`.

Comment: Is this baed on the result of a SQL query? Then setting the timezone in the PHP configuration might not be enough - can you share the raw values?

Comment: maybe its not according for the timezone because my mssql database the datefrom and dateto columns are nvarchar(50). My raw date is ex: 20.06.2018

Answer (score 0):

you server is based in a different location and in a different time zone. If its imperative you have your time simple get the time and add or subtract the difference. I had similar problem with 1and1 internet.